# one inputtext diable 4 other input text and any of the 4 disable the one

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces, facelets

I have 5 inputtext in my jsf page. I want to achieve this functionality that If some text in entered in first inputtext, rest 4 should be disabled. And if any text is entered in any of the remaining 4 inputtexts then the 1st inputtext should be disbaled. I am quite new to jsf and don't know how to do this. Anyone please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JSF 2 you can do it by this.

```
<h:inputText id="inputOne" value="#{bean.value1}" disabled="#{not empty bean.value2}">
    <f:ajax event="keyup" render="inputTwo"/>
</h:inputText>
<h:inputText id="inputTwo" value="#{bean.value2}" disabled="#{not empty bean.value1}">
    <f:ajax event="keyup" render="inputOne"/>
</h:inputText>
```

If you have a lot of fields, it is better to introduce method in `#{bean}` to perform all checks in more simple way than `#{not empty bean.value1 and not empty bean.value2 and not empty bean.value3}`

In case of many grouped inputs that should be disabled, you can either list them space separated in `render` attribute of `<f:ajax>` tag or group them with `<h:panelGroup/>` and render the whole group.

```
<h:inputText id="inputOne" value="#{bean.value1}" disabled="#{not empty bean.value2 and not empty bean.value3 and not empty bean.value4}">
    <f:ajax event="keyup" render="inputs"/>
</h:inputText>
<h:panelGroup id="inputs">
    <h:inputText value="#{bean.value2}" disabled="#{not empty bean.value1}">
        <f:ajax event="keyup" render="inputOne"/>
    </h:inputText>
    <h:inputText value="#{bean.value3}" disabled="#{not empty bean.value1}">
        <f:ajax event="keyup" render="inputOne"/>
    </h:inputText>
    <h:inputText value="#{bean.value4}" disabled="#{not empty bean.value1}">
        <f:ajax event="keyup" render="inputOne"/>
    </h:inputText>
</h:panelGroup>
```

Comment: in <f:ajax event="keyup" render="inputTwo"/>, will 'render="inputTwo"' be having remaining inputtext ids or just one will do

Comment: i have placed these all inputtexts in table and each inputtext is having its own id. is it possible to use 4 inputext id's in render attribute.

Comment: I would like to follow this approach suggested by you - @GKlimov : If you have a lot of fields, it is better to introduce method in #{bean} to perform all checks in more simple way than #{not empty bean.value1 and not empty bean.value2 and not empty bean.value3}.   What should I need to do to achieve this.

Comment: As I said, you can list your ids in `render` space-separated. "What should I need to do to achieve this." - here you need to add method to managed bean. Something like `public boolean isDisableValue1() {return StringUtils.isNotBlank(value2) && StringUtils.isNotBlank(value3) && StringUtils.isNotBlank(value4); }` and use it in `disabled` attribute: `<h:inputText disabled="#{bean.disableValue1}"/>`

Comment: Thank you GKlimov. I have done it using  `render` space-separated id's and it's working. The only issue left is when I delete from inputtext1 using backspace and make it empty then other four becomes enabled.. while if I delete the whole text from inputtext1 at once, remaining 4 inputtext are still disabled. I will try to solve it by using the method in managed bean. Thank you so much for the help.